# Prove this equation

Tags: lateral-thinking

5 + 5 + 5 = 550

By one stroke of a pen, prove the above equation. Use your imagination !

> Hint: Can be solved better on a piece of paper.

Comment: Please edit the title into the puzzle

Answer (score 5):

> Draw a 45 degree line and turn the + to a `4`.
>  $5 +5+5 = 550$ becomes $545 + 5 = 550$

Comment: Nice one, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

Easy one !

> 5+5+5 ≠ 550 is valid

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

> 5 + 5 + 5 ≤ 550

Another solution is:

> 5 + 5 + 5 ≠ 550